# How to compute the exterior derivative of a 1-form on projectivization of a vector space

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $V$ be a complex vector space, and let $\mathbb{P}(V)$ denote the projectivization of $V$ (i.e. space of 1-dimensional subspaces, i.e. 1st Grassmanian). Suppose further that $V$ is endowed with a non-degenerate two-form $\omega$.

We know that the tangent space $T_v\mathbb{P}(V)$ is canonically isomorphic to $V/\left<v\right>$. We can thus define a 1-form $\alpha$ by the maps

$$\alpha_v(\cdot)=\omega(v,\cdot),$$

which is well defined since $\omega(v,v)=0$. My question is how I can explicitly compute the exterior derivative $d\alpha$. The reason I ask this is that I am trying to do Exercise 10.1 in Voisin's "Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry i", where they ask to show that the top dimensional form $\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^{n-1}$ does not vanish at any point, and I feel that I can't do the exercise if I don't know how to compute $d\alpha$.

EDIT: Below is the exercise in question.

> Let $V$ be a complex vector space endowed with a non-degenerate 2-form $\omega$. Recall that $T_{\mathbb{P}(V),v}$ is isomorphic to $V/\left<v\right>$. Show that the form $\alpha$ defined (up to multiplicative coefficient) by
> $$\alpha_v(\cdot)=\omega(v,\cdot)$$
> provides a contact structure on $\mathbb{P}(V)$

Contact structures are defined above as follows:

> Let $X$ be a complex manifold of dimension $2n-1$ a contact structure on $X$ is determined by the local datum of a holomorphic $1$-form $\alpha$ which is well defined up to multiplication by an invertible holomorphic function and which satisfies the condition that the $(2n-1)$-form
> $$\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^{n-1}\in K_X$$
> does not vanish at any point.

Comment: Choose a basis of $V$ and write everything out with respect to affine coordinates with respect to the basis.

Comment: @Deane Okay, makes sense. I was hoping there would be an easier way...

Comment: I don't think it's so hard that way. And as or after you do it, you'll probably see a more abstract approach that works.

Comment: I disagree with your "canonical isomorphic" (see the Euler sequence). I'm also confused: How is $\alpha$ giving you a well-defined $1$-form at $[v]$? On what manifold is $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^{n-1}$ a top-degree form?

Comment: I also have a hard-time picturing how your form $\alpha$ does not depend on the representative $v\in [v]$.

Comment: @Didier I suspect we're talking about a form on the tautological bundle on $\Bbb P(V)$, but the top degree still doesn't work out.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm confused too. I'm just trying to understand the exercise...

Comment: What you’ve put in this post is definitely incorrect. Can you edit the post to include the exact and complete statement of the exercise?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for your help. I have edited the question to include the original problem statement.

Comment: Since the computation depends on a (“local”) choice of section of the tautological bundle, I suspect you should just follow Deane’s advice. The alternative I might suggest is to apply Cartan’s formula for the Lie derivative, $L_X = \iota_Xd + d\iota_X$. And the form is a top-degree form only working in the holomorphic category :) That is clear now. (The tangent space statement is still wrong. Of course, any two $n$-dim. vector spaces are isomorphic.)

Comment: @TedShifrin, why is the tangent space statement wrong? Isn't $T_{[v]}\mathbb{P}V$ naturally isomorphic (i.e., independent of basis) to $V/[v]$?

Comment: @Deane: It's isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(\text{Span}(v),V/\text{Span}(v))$. There's an $\mathscr O(1)$ twist.

Comment: @TedShifrin, yes. Ironically, I remember this better for Grassmannians in general.